# How to record current client state and re-sync at a later date

Tags: perforce

My client workspace is in some sync'd state. some folders/files could be sync'd to specific change lists. 
I want to record the current state of my client workspace so that i can replicate at some later date.

p4 "record my state" > state.txt
p4 sync < state.txt

Can the output from "p4 have" be used with "p4 sync".
Can p4 changes be used?

I am also considering create a label and using p4 labelsync.
Are labels "expensive"? (size on server , or performance of server)
I could be building my product N times a day. if i create a new label every time i will quickly end up with a huge number of labels.

Thx
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is via labels, as you suggest.  You are correct that this can potentially get expensive in terms of space, since the size of a static label (i.e. one where each file's revision is recorded individually) scales linearly with the number of files.

Syncing individual folders and files to individual changelists, while something that Perforce makes possible, is probably an antipattern if you're doing it as part of a routine build process that needs to be reproducible rather than as a one-off debugging operation.  Build configurations should be versioned in some way -- if you sync everything in your workspace to a single changelist, the changelist itself is the unit of versioning (and a changelist is only a single int worth of information -- very space-efficient).

Typically if you need different components at different versions to make a particular build, you'd want to record that in the form of a stream or a branch, since these are objects that can be properly versioned, and potentially stored more efficiently than a series of labels.

The output of `p4 have` and `p4 changes` can both be used with `p4 sync` if formatted correctly.  The `-F` global formatting flag is useful there; for example you can run a command like `p4 -F %depotFile%%haveRev% have` to turn the output of `p4 have` into a list of simple `file#rev` arguments that you can pipe to `p4 -x - sync`.  See https://web.archive.org/web/20141008214721/https://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting for more information.

Comment: Thx. really helpful. Just a note the -F is not well documented on Perforce web site. it took me a while to find that the formatting flax is %haveRev% and not %depotRev% (which doesnt exist).

Comment: I was having trouble finding a link, but finally got it via the wayback machine, editing answer.